# I am trying to combine a string while looping

Tags: javascript, jquery

The result I am trying to get if the first two boxes are checked would be 1 2, if 3 boxes are checked the result would be 1 2 3. The x comes out as undefined. I assume this has to do with variable scope but even if I view the x within the input function it only shows 1 selection at a time, it is not combing them.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function MLSNumbersSelected()
{
    $("input:checkbox").each(function(){  
        var $this = $(this);    
        if($this.is(":checked")){
        var x = x+" "+$this.attr("id");
        }
    });
  alert(x); //should equal what is checked for example 1 or 1 2.
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="checkBoxes">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" id="1" />1<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" id="2" />2<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" id="3" />3</p>
    <p>
            Check off some options then click button.
      <input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Click to Test" onClick="MLSNumbersSelected()">
    </p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are defining x everytime in your loop, instead define x once and keep appending to it through the loop. 
Eg:

```
    <script>
    function MLSNumbersSelected()
    {
        var x;
        $("input:checkbox").each(function(){  
            var $this = $(this);    
            if($this.is(":checked")){
                x += " "+$this.attr("id");
            }
        });
        alert(x); //should equal what is checked for example 1 or 1 2.
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare x outside the `.each()` loop.  As it is now, it is declared inside the `.each()` loop and then it goes out of scope before the next callback is called so you can't accumulate it's value from one callback to the next:

```
function MLSNumbersSelected() {
    var x = "";
    $("input:checkbox").each(function(){  
        if (this.checked) {
            x += " " + this.id;
        }
    });
    console.log(x);
}
```

FYI, I also removed the use of the jQuery from inside the loop because it's not necessary when the direct DOM properties give you everything you need already.

---

You could also let the selector do the work for you, by adding `:checked` to the selector so it only selects checkboxes that are already checked.  And, you can then use `.map()` and `.join()` to more easily create the list:

```
function MLSNumbersSelected() {
    var x = $("input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){  
        return this.id;
    }).get().join(" ");
    console.log(x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You re-initialize x in the loop. This should solve your issue:

```
function MLSNumbersSelected()
{
    var x = '';    
    $("input:checkbox").each(function(){  
        var $this = $(this);    
        if($this.is(":checked")){
        x = x+" "+$this.attr("id");
        }
    });
  alert(x); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this to see if it achieve what you need:

```
var inputs = $("input:checkbox");
inputs.each(function(i){  
    if(inputs.eq(i).is(":checked")){
    x = x+" "+inputs.eq(i).attr("id");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
    $('#button').on('click', function() {
        var x = $(':checkbox:checked').map(function() {
            return this.id;
        })
        .get().join(' ');
        alert( x );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <p id="checkBoxes">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" id="1" />1<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" id="2" />2<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" id="3" />3</p>
    <p>
            Check off some options then click button.
      <input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Click to Test">
    </p>
```